# Как вывести пользователей в группе безопасности Windows AD

Tags: c++, python, windows, active-directory, pywin32

Доброго времени суток! Нужно вывести список пользователей в группе безопасности Windows AD  предположительно с помощью Win32API. Скорее всего такая функция есть в одном из модулей win32api, но найти её в документации пока не смог. Кто знает, прошу помочь.

Comment: Работайте с AD как с LDAP-сервером если нет особой необходимости winapi юзать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как раз сегодня решал такую же задачу на Python:

```
import random
from ldap3 import Connection, Server, NTLM, ALL, ALL_ATTRIBUTES

def get_ldap_grp_members(
    ldap_conn,
    group_name,
    search_base,
    attr_name='sAMAccountName'
):
    res = []
    ldap_conn.search(search_base, "(&(CN={}))".format(group_name))
    for cn in ldap_conn.entries:
        ldap_conn.search(search_base,
                         '(memberOf={})'.format(cn.entry_dn),
                         attributes=[ALL_ATTRIBUTES])
        #print("parsing: [{}]".format(cn.entry_dn))
        res.extend([x.entry_attributes_as_dict.get(attr_name)[0]
                    for x in ldap_conn.entries])
    return list(set(res))

# list of Windows Domain Controller servers
ldap_srv_list = ["dc1.company.com","dc2.company.com","dc3.company.com"]
ldap_srv = Server(random.choice(ldap_srv_list), get_info=ALL)

user=r'DOMAIN_NAME\windows_login'
pwd='windows_password'

c = Connection(ldap_srv, user=user, password=pwd, authentication=NTLM, auto_bind=True)
```

Пример:

```
users = get_ldap_grp_members(c, 'AD_group_name', search_base='dc=server,dc=com')
```

В качестве имени группы можно использовать маски:

```
users = get_ldap_grp_members(c, 'Group*Admin*', search_base='dc=server,dc=com')
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, вариант с ldap понятен. 
От себя добавлю, раз уж спрашивал про win32api, функция действительно есть:

```
import win32net
import win32netcon as netcon
group_name = "bestgroup.local"
level = 10
print win32net.NetUserEnum(group_name, level, netcon.FILTER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT)
```

Проблема была в том, что с win32api работаю недавно и искал ответ в win32security