# Python3. LDAP3. Вывести список пользователей AD с переменным набором атрибутов

Tags: python-3.x, list, active-directory, ldap

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SUBTREE

attr = ['msExchIMMetaPhysicalURL', 'msExchEwsEnabled', 'msExchELCExpirySuspensionStart',
        'msExchEwsApplicationAccessPolicy', 'msExchExtensionCustomAttribute5', 'unmergedAtts',
        'msExchMailboxMoveRemoteHostName', 'msExchTransportInboundSettings', 'publicDelegates', 'msExchResourceGUID',
        'msExchUnmergedAttsPt', 'msExchUMAddresses', 'msExchOriginatingForest', 'msExchMDBRulesQuota']

AD_SERVER = '192.168.1.1'
AD_USER = 'XXX\Adm'
AD_PASSWORD = input()
AD_SEARCH_TREE = 'dc=XXX, dc=XX'

#соединяюсь с сервером. всё ОК
server = Server(AD_SERVER)
conn = Connection(server, user=AD_USER, password=AD_PASSWORD)
conn.bind()

#читаю список пользоватей со "всеми" атрибутами
conn.search(AD_SEARCH_TREE, '(objectCategory=person)', SUBTREE, attributes=attr)
print(len(conn.entries))

i = 0
j = 0
#пытаюсь вывести первых 5 пользователей с 10 атрибутами каждый
while i < 5:
    while j < 10:
        print(conn.entries[i].attr[j])
        j = j + 1
    j = 0 
    i = i + 1
    print('=====================================================================‚)
```

Получаю ошибку

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/kn/PycharmProjects/ad-und-tabelle/AD.py", line 215, in
>   
>       print(conn.entries[i].attr[j])   File "/Users/kn/Dropbox/Personal/Python/Muster/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ldap3/abstract/entry.py",
>   line 192, in **getattr**
>       raise LDAPCursorError(error_message) ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPCursorError: attribute 'attr' not found

Если тут `print(conn.entries[i].attr[j])` поставить `print(conn.entries[I]. msExchIMMetaPhysicalURL)` или print`(conn.entries[i].msExchEwsEnabled)` или любой другой атрибут явно указать, то вывод нормальный.
Если по-максимуму, то требуется сформировать таблицу где по Х названия атрибутов записи AD, по Y значения атрибута cn. В ячейках на пересечении соответственно значения атрибутов.

Comment: попробуйте воспользоваться `entry_attributes_as_dict` - [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/780775/211923)

Comment: Совет хороший. Но не понимаю как работает        res.extend([x.entry_attributes_as_dict.get(attr_name)[0]
                    for x in ldap_conn.entries])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А ларчик просто открывался.
вот это

```
conn.entries[i].attr[j]
```

меняем на вот это

```
conn.entries[i][attr[j]]
```